# optimizing two variable function.

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming

I want to optimize the following objective function subjected to the constraint as given below:
$$ min \hspace{2mm} ||x||_1+j$$ 
$$s.t. \hspace{2mm} ||Ax-\frac{1}{j}(b_1+b_2+\ldots +b_k)||_2 \leq \epsilon \\
1\leq j \leq k\\$$

$\text{where}, \\
A=m \times n \hspace{2mm} \text{matrix and is known.}\\
x=n \times 1 \hspace{2mm} \text{vector}\\
b_i, i=1,2, \ldots k \hspace{2mm} \hspace{2mm} \text{all} \hspace{2mm} m \times 1 \hspace{2mm} \text{vector and are known.}\\
j=\text{total numbers of $b_i$}$

where, the $k$ is fixed integer value and $j$ is in between $1$ and $k$. Can anyone please suggest me how can I proceed this further. I want average of $j$ $b_i'\text{s}, i=1,2 \ldots k$ and $x$ which minimizes the given objective function. Any general method to solve the given optimization problem?

Comment: Your formulation is unclear in that $n$ appears as a constant (the number of columns of $A$ and the length of $x$) and as a variable.  Should we assume that $A$ has $n_{\max}$ columns and that you're looking for a solution in which only the first $n$ entries in $x$ are allowed to be nonzero?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have updated the question. Please have a look and $x$ has $s \ll n$ non-zero entries.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused here.  You want to minimize over $x$ and $j$, with $n$ and $k$ fixed, right?  Shouldn't the term inside the norm be $(1/j)(b_{1}+\ldots+b_{j})$?

Answer (score 1):

For each fixed $j$, this is a straight forward problem that can be solved by iterative soft threshholding (ISTA), FISTA, ADMM, IRLS, etc.

Unless the $b_{i}$ vectors have some special property that you haven't told us about, there's no reason to believe that you do better than solving the problem for $j=1$, $2$, $\ldots$, $k$ and then pick the best objective value you found.